# Elasticsearch analytics percent

Tags: elasticsearch, analytics

I am using Elasticsearch 1.7.3 to accumulate data for analytics reports.

I have an index that holds documents where each document has a numeric field called 'duration' (how many milliseconds the request took), and a string field called 'component'. There can be many documents with the same component name.

Eg.

```
{"component": "A", "duration": 10}
{"component": "B", "duration": 27}
{"component": "A", "duration": 5}
{"component": "C", "duration": 2}
```

I would like to produce a report that states for each component:

The sum of all 'duration' fields for this component.

```
A: 15
B: 27
C: 2
```

The percentage of this sum out of the total sum of duration of **all** documents.  In my example

```
A: (10+5) / (10+27+5+2) * 100
B: 27 / (10+27+5+2) * 100
C: 2 / (10+27+5+2) * 100
```

The percentage of the documents for each component, out of the total components.

```
A: 2 / 4 * 100
B: 1 / 4 * 100
C: 1 / 4 * 100
```

How do I do that with Elasticsearch 1.7.3?

Comment: I mean, how do I do that in one single query.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508321/elasticsearch-calculate-percentage-for-each-bucket-from-total

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With ES 1.7.3, there is no way to compute data based on the results of two different aggregations, this is something that can be done in ES 2.0 with [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-pipeline.html), though.

However, what you're asking is not too complicated to do on the client-side with 1.7.3. If you use the query below, you'll get all you need to get the figures you expect:

```
POST components/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "total_duration": {
         "sum": {
            "field": "duration"
         }
      },
      "components": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "component"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "duration_sum": {
               "sum": {
                  "field": "duration"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The results would look like this:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "total_duration": {
         "value": 44
      },
      "components": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "a",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "duration_sum": {
                  "value": 15
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "b",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "duration_sum": {
                  "value": 27
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "c",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "duration_sum": {
                  "value": 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Now all you need to do would be the following. I'm using JavaScript, but you can do it in any other language that can read JSON.

```
var response = ...the JSON response above...
var total_duration = response.aggregations.total_duration.value;
var total_docs = response.hits.total;

response.aggregations.components.buckets.forEach(function(comp_stats) {
    // total duration for the component
    var total_duration_comp = comp_stats.duration_sum.value;

    // percentage duration of the component
    var perc_duration_comp = total_duration_comp / total_duration * 100;

    // percentage documents for the component
    var perc_doc_comp = comp_stats.doc_count / total_docs * 100;
});
```

Comment: I wanted to answer that.. :-( . Perfect summary @Val

Comment: Thank you Val. My initial query was more or less the same, however I was trying to extend it
to fetch the rest of the statistics I needed in the same GET query.
I did not realize I had to use extra code to fetch the rest of the info.

Comment: I have moved to ES 2.0, so now I can use pipeline aggregations. Which pipeline aggregation will help me achieve my requirement?

Comment: @TsiyonaDershowitz: It looks like you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508321/elasticsearch-calculate-percentage-for-each-bucket-from-total

Answer (score 0):

In ElasticSearch[2.x], You can use the [bucket script aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html), which is perfectly meet your needs!

eg:

```
{
    "bucket_script": {
        "buckets_path": {
            "my_var1": "the_sum", 
            "my_var2": "the_value_count"
        },
        "script": "my_var1 / my_var2"
    }
}
```

detail:

```
POST /sales/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "sales_per_month" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "total_sales": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "price"
                    }
                },
                "t-shirts": {
                  "filter": {
                    "term": {
                      "type": "t-shirt"
                    }
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "sales": {
                      "sum": {
                        "field": "price"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "t-shirt-percentage": {
                    "bucket_script": {
                        "buckets_path": {
                          "tShirtSales": "t-shirts>sales",
                          "totalSales": "total_sales"
                        },
                        "script": "params.tShirtSales / params.totalSales * 100"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```