# Percentage for each bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im trying to get the percentage for each bucket in elasticsearch 7.1 with this query:

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "group_by_status":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"status.keyword"
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "percentage":{  
               "sum":{  
                  "script":"100/total"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "total":{  
         "sum_bucket":{  
            "buckets_path":"group_by_status>_count"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This one doesnt work because you cant use the total count of status and I get error that the variable total is not define but I want to know if theres a way to get this result with the percentage of each bucket:

```
{  
   "aggregations":{  
      "group_by_status":{  
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[  
            {  
               "key":"Abierto",
               "doc_count":2,
               "percentage":{  
                  "value":40.0
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"Cerrado",
               "doc_count":2,
               "percentage":{  
                  "value":40.0
               }
            },
            {  
               "key":"Pausado",
               "doc_count":1,
               "percentage":{  
                  "value":20.0
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "total":{  
         "value":5.0
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible and you may have to manage this at the service layer. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47911014/3838328 for your reference.