# Elasticsearch aggregation to get difference in date per bucket

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-painless

I would like to find the difference between the min date of a series of buckets and the the date of that bucket.  For instance I have an elastic aggregation similar to below

```
        "id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "data.id"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "min_date": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "data.dateSold"
                    }
                },
                "date": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "data.dateSold",
                        "calendar_interval": "year"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "sales": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "data.sales"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this produces a result similar too

```
{
    "uwi": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 8559203,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "Tshirts",
                "doc_count": 1826,
                "date_histogram#date": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key_as_string": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                            "key": 1609459200000,
                            "doc_count": 364,
                            "sum#sales": {
                                "value": 31438.67796
                            }
                        },
                         {
                            "key_as_string": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                            "key": 1640995200000,
                            "doc_count": 365,
                            "sum#sales": {
                                "value": 16095.7913
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "min#min_date": {
                    "value": 1609459200000,
                    "value_as_string": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
...
...
```

I would like to add an extra value per bucket that is the difference between the date (key) and the min date e.g. I get a result similar to below with an extra *'difference_with_min_date'* value per bucket which is the diff between the *'min#min_date'* agg and that buckets '*key*'

```
{
    "uwi": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 8559203,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "Tshirts",
                "doc_count": 1826,
                "date_histogram#date": {
                    "buckets": [
                        {
                            "key_as_string": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                            "key": 1609459200000,
                            "doc_count": 364,
                            sum#sales": {
                                "value": 31438.67796
                            },
                           "difference_with_min_date": { 
                                    "value": 0
                            }
                        },
                         {
                            "key_as_string": "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                            "key": 1640995200000,
                            "doc_count": 365,
                            "sum#sales": {
                                "value": 16095.7913
                            },
                            "difference_with_min_date": { 
                                    "value": 31536000000
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "min#min_date": {
                    "value": 1609459200000,
                    "value_as_string": "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
...
...
```

Any ideas would be helpful, I have tried to do this with a script with little success as you need to supply the bucket_script path within the *'sales'* aggs (ie as a sibling) to do it per bucket value but then you cant reference the uncle min aggregation.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElasticSearch calculate percentage for each bucket from total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508321/elasticsearch-calculate-percentage-for-each-bucket-from-total)

Comment: Hi Andy, are you referring to the limitation mentioned in the question of not being able to reference 'uncle' aggregations?  I mentioned this limitation in my question.  I was wondering if anyone can think of a workaround to solve the problem in a way that is supported e.g. if I could work out how to make the min#date a sibling of the buckets then I could get it to work.  Cheers